# Launching an editor from a pipelined command

Tags: shell, sh, pipeline

I have a script `myscript` that collects some information, put them in a temporary file, launches `$EDITOR` on that file and waits for the user to be done. Something similar to what happens with `git commit` when it opens `$EDITOR` to let you enter a commit message.

Basically `myscript` is

```
salt=$(collect_salt_from_various_sources)
password=$(openssl passwd -salt $salt $$)

tempfile=$(mktemp)
printf "username=CHOOSE A NAME\npassword=$password\n" > $tempfile

$EDITOR $tempfile
# read data from $tempfile
```

I would like to use my script in a pipeline, so to receive information from stdin:

```
# "aabbcc" will be used as part of the salt
echo "aabbcc" | myscript
```

The problem here is that command-line editors (e.g., Vim, Nano) cannot access the terminal any longer and the user is not able to type (almost) anything.

Is there a way to launch `$EDITOR` from a pipelined script so that command line editors still work?

Comment: I doubt it. But considering the `git commit` analogy, wouldn't a reasonable alternative be to add a switch, so that `myscript -m 'my precious data'` would work?

Comment: do you want to append the stdout (`my precious data`) to the tempfile and then open in editor? when and how would you use the `my precious data`?

Comment: I expanded the example to make the relation between stdin and the data in the edited file more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`vipe`](http://git.kitenet.net/?p=moreutils.git;a=blob;f=vipe;h=adc44a06055de36017d3395cf2756aa8fa170ad0;hb=HEAD) command from moreutils needs to solve a similar problem and uses this technique:

1. It writes everything from STDIN to a temporary file

   ```
   my ($fh, $tmp)=tempfile();
   print ($fh <STDIN>) || die "write temp: $!";
   close STDIN;
   ```
2. It redirects STDIN and STDOUT to `/dev/tty`

   ```
   open(STDIN, "</dev/tty") || die "reopen stdin: $!";
   open(OUT, ">&STDOUT") || die "save stdout: $!";
   close STDOUT;
   open(STDOUT, ">/dev/tty") || die "reopen stdout: $!";
   ```
3. Launches `$EDITOR`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to modify your shell script, but I agree with you that you cannot use a pipeline with vim or nano... Unless you add a `-` at the end of the command!

```
echo "foo" | $EDITOR -
```

This will work with nano and vim.

---

**Second chance:**

After many tries, I made this script work (I hope this is more or less the result you would like):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $tempfile | vim -R -
```

And it is called by:

```
echo "foo" | sh myscript.sh
```

The only annoying thing is that I can't get rid of this message from vim:

```
Vim: Reading from stdin...
```

Comment: The data on stdin is not meant to be edited by the user, it is useful only to the script; `$EDITOR` must edit the supplied `$tempfile` so that I can later read it back.

Comment: Yes, some editors are able to work around that problem with the correct flags. I was looking for a generic solution to embed in a script to be distributed with no knowledge of how `$EDITOR` will be set.